# Creating multidimensional arrays & matrices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array

Trying to create a function `mCreate()` that given a set a numbers returns a multidimensional array (matrix):

```
mCreate(2, 2, 2)    
//   [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

When this functions handles just 2 levels of depth ie: `mCreate(2, 2) //[[0, 0], [0, 0]]` I know to do 2 levels, you can use 2 nested `for loops` but the problem I'm having is how to handle an n'th number of arguments.

Would this problem be better approached with recursion, otherwise how can I dynamically determine the number of nested `for loops` I'm going to need given the number of arguments?

ps: the most performant way would be great but not essential

**RE-EDIT** - After using Benchmark.js to check perf the results were as follows:

```
BenLesh x 82,043 ops/sec ±2.56% (83 runs sampled)
Phil-P x 205,852 ops/sec ±2.01% (81 runs sampled)
Brian x 252,508 ops/sec ±1.17% (89 runs sampled)
Rick-H x 287,988 ops/sec ±1.25% (82 runs sampled)
Rodney-R x 97,930 ops/sec ±1.67% (81 runs sampled)
Fastest is Rick-H
```

@briancavalier also came up with a good solution [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/mufugu/edit?js,console):

```
const mCreate = (...sizes) => (initialValue) => _mCreate(sizes, initialValue, sizes.length-1, 0)

const _mCreate = (sizes, initialValue, len, index) =>
    Array.from({ length: sizes[index] }, () => 
        index === len ? initialValue : _mCreate(sizes, initialValue, len, index+1))
mCreate(2, 2, 2)(0)
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: `function mCreate(...arg){}`

Comment: @PranavCBalan this would only return `[2, 2, 2]` not what I'm after :(

Comment: @cmdv : you can get n arguments , then using some method implement what you want

Comment: I would suggest using object as parameter. `var o = {size:2, depth:2, count:2}; mCreate(o)`

Comment: @Rajesh unfortunately that wouldn't cover `mCreate(2,2,2,2)`

Comment: Can you explain meaning of each parameter? Are you trying create nested array based on parameters? So in this case, this would go for 3rd level?

Comment: trying to replicate `math.zeros(2,2,2)` but having the ability to add nth number of values. This is for use with matrices. http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html

Comment: @RickHitchcock it would contain 1 element

Comment: @cmdv Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple recursive answer is this (in ES2015):

```js
const mCreate = (...sizes) => 
    Array.from({ length: sizes[0] }, () => 
        sizes.length === 1 ? 0 : mCreate(...sizes.slice(1)));
```

[JS Bin here](http://jsbin.com/redahikusi/1/edit?js,console)

EDIT: I think I'd add the initializer in with a higher order function though:

```
const mCreate = (...sizes) => (initialValue) => 
    Array.from({ length: sizes[0] }, () => 
        sizes.length === 1 ? initialValue : mCreate(...sizes.slice(1))(initialValue));
```

Which could be used like:

```
mCreate(2, 2, 2)('hi'); 
// [[["hi", "hi"], ["hi", "hi"]], [["hi", "hi"], ["hi", "hi"]]]
```

[JSBin of that](http://jsbin.com/vimutudile/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-recursive solution:

```
function mCreate() {
  var result = 0, i;

  for(i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    result = new Array(arguments[i]).fill(result);
  }

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

The JSON functions are used to mimic a deep clone, but that causes the function to be non-performant.

```js
function mCreate() {
  var result = 0, i;
  
  for(i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    result = new Array(arguments[i]).fill(result);
  }

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(mCreate(2, 2, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(mCreate(1, 2, 3, 4)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(mCreate(5)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(mCreate(1, 5)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(mCreate(5, 1)));

var m = mCreate(1, 2, 3, 4);
m[0][1][1][3] = 4;
console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
```

Comment: this looks great, do you think it would be more performant than a recursive option?

Comment: Yes, because a recursive solution would add the execution context to the stack for each dimension.

Comment: woah that looks really clean it's also improved the perf!! was not expecting that, though the test I'm running are really bad and on jsfiddle!!

Comment: This solution has a slight problem once you start modifying values of the generated array. for `var x = mCreate(2, 1);` the following is true: `x[0] === x[1]`. So if you did `x[0][0] = 1`; you would also have `x[1][0] === 1`. Using .slice() when "cloning" the array would solve that.

Comment: @rodneyrehm, great point!  Unfortunately, `.slice()` does a narrow copy, and we'd need a deep copy instead.  My solution needs more work.

Comment: @RickHitchcock you're correct about the shallow copy. But since you'd be creating a shallow copy on every iteration, you'd end up with unique arrays on every level. If this problem were about code size rather than runtime performance, you could also just run a `return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));` at the end.

Comment: Now updated using the JSON functions and Array.prototype.fill().  Super-short, but no longer performant.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive algorithms *may* be easier to reason about, but generally they're not *required*. In this particular case the iterative approach is simple enough.

Your problem consists of two parts:

1. creating an array with variable number of `0`-value elements
2. creating variable number of arrays of previously created arrays

Here's an implementation of what I *think* you're trying to create:

```
function nested() {
  // handle the deepest level first, because we need to generate the zeros
  var result = [];
  for (var zeros = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; zeros > 0; zeros--) {
    result.push(0);
  }

  // for every argument, walking backwards, we clone the
  // previous result as often as requested by that argument
  for (var i = arguments.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    var _clone = [];
    for (var clones = arguments[i]; clones > 0; clones--) {
      // result.slice() returns a shallow copy
      _clone.push(result.slice(0));
    }

    result = _clone;
  }

  if (arguments.length > 2) {
    // the shallowly copying the array works fine for 2 dimensions,
    // but for higher dimensions, we need to compensate
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Since writing the algorithm is only *half* of the solution, here's the test to  verify our function actually performs the way we want it to. We'd typically use one of the gazillion test runners (e.g. [mocha](http://mochajs.org/) or [AVA](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava)). But since I don't know your setup (if any), we'll just do this manually:

```
var tests = [
  {
    // the arguments we want to pass to the function.
    // translates to nested(2, 2)
    input: [2, 2],
    // the result we expect the function to return for
    // the given input
    output: [
      [0, 0],
      [0, 0]
    ]
  },
  {
    input: [2, 3],
    output: [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0]
    ]
  },
  {
    input: [3, 2],
    output: [
      [0, 0],
      [0, 0],
      [0, 0]
    ]
  },
  {
    input: [3, 2, 1],
    output: [
      [
        [0], [0]
      ],
      [
        [0], [0]
      ],
      [
        [0], [0]
      ]
    ]
  },
];

tests.forEach(function(test) {
  // execute the function with the input array as arguments
  var result = nested.apply(null, test.input);
  // verify the result is correct
  var matches = JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(test.output);
  if (!matches) {
    console.error('failed input', test.input);
    console.log('got', result, 'but expected', rest.output);
  } else {
    console.info('passed', test.input);
  }
});
```

It's up to you to define and handle edge-cases, like `nested(3, 0)`, `nested(0, 4)`, `nested(3, -1)` or `nested(-1, 2)`.

Comment: thank you for the great explanation, I'm just going to quickly set up proper perf tests but using a quick jsfiddle from Phil-plückthun, looks like @rick-hitchcock it comming out top :-)  https://jsfiddle.net/2v4zj76t/

Comment: Rick's solution is not cloning the arrays, thereby producing a result that cannot be mutated without side-effects. If that's a problem and you fix that, both functions would be doing the same thing and performance should be equal.

Comment: I would much rather it cloned the arrays as I'm trying to use this function towards this FP library I've been trying to write https://github.com/Cmdv/linearJs

Comment: @cmdv if Math.js already has the function you need, why not simply load that as a dependency and be done with it? I mean, the library is APL, documented and tested. It has >3k stars. From where I stand you're wasting your time re-implementing this already solved problem… You even could only only load the zeros module: https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/lib/function/matrix/zeros.js - why do this again?

Comment: Your solution also needs a deep copy.  See https://jsfiddle.net/8k5w0gvh/.  There should be only one "2"

Comment: oh boy. I've only tested the reference issue for 2 dimensions, not 3. You're right and I've added a deep-clone cop out to my answer…

Comment: @rodneyrehm I know it's available but I'm wanting to build my own linearJs library without any peer dependencies, thank you for the help it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Pranav, you should use `arguments` object.

#### Recursion + arguments object

```js
function mCreate() {
  var args = arguments;
  var result = [];
  if (args.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
      var new_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);
      result.push(mCreate.apply(this, new_args));
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < args[0]; i++) {
      result.push(0)
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function print(obj) {
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
}
print(mCreate(2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Comment: thanks the only thing that draws me away is the use of `apply` as thats a pretty slow process but I like the recursion :)

Answer (score 0):

The gist is to pass in the result of a `create` as the second argument of `create` except for the last (or the first depending on how you look at it) instance:

```
function create(n, v) {
  let arr = Array(n || 0);
  if (v !== undefined) arr.fill(v);
  return arr;
}

create(2, create(2, 0)); // [[0,0],[0,0]]
create(2, create(2, create(2, 0))); // [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]]]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/94ac87o4/)

Using a loop we can build up array dimensions:

```
function loop(d, l) {
  var out = create(d, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < l - 1; i++) {
    out = create(d, out);
  }
  return out;
}

loop(2,2) // [[0,0],[0,0]]
loop(2,3) // [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]]]
loop(1,3) // [[[0]]]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/94ac87o4/1/)