# Creating multidimensional arrays in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the cleanest way of allocating a multidimentional array in javascript? Or is it even necessary? Currently I am doing it like so

`let dp = new Array(8).fill(null).map(item =>(new Array(8).fill(null).map(item =>(new Array(8).fill(null)))));`

(for 8x8x8).

Or can i just do `let dp = new Array(); dp[1][1][1] = 7`? Wondering the best way to do stuff like this

Comment: *"Or can i just do..."* Just try it and see for yourself :)

Comment: `var multi = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]` You just have to experiment.

Comment: the cleanest way is one that everyone can understand without having headache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multidimensional arrays & matrices in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36969154/218196)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to create a `makeArr` function which recursively calls itself, to which you can pass a nested object indicating the length and values desired, something like this:

```js
const makeArr = (length, item) => Array.from(
  { length },
  () => typeof item === 'object' ? makeArr(item.length, item.item) : item
);

const arrx3x3 = makeArr(3, { length: 3, item: { length: 3, item: 0 } });

// check that every array is a separate reference:
arrx3x3[0][0][0] = 1;
console.log(arrx3x3);
```

This will allow for relatively clean creation of arbitrary array dimensions.

If every nested array will have the same length, then you just need to indicate the `length` on the first parameter to `makeArr`:

```js
const makeArr = (length, item) => Array.from(
  { length },
  () => typeof item === 'object' ? makeArr(length, item.item) : item
);

const arrx3x3 = makeArr(3, { item: { item: 0 } });

// check that every array is a separate reference:
arrx3x3[0][0][0] = 1;
console.log(arrx3x3);
```

If you want to fill the nested array items with non-array objects (eg where the `0` is now, in the nested `item : 0`), you'll have to change the `typeof item === 'object'` test to something more precise.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Array.from()` and pass an array of size, and a value (`val`) for the last arrays. Use array destructuring, and rest to get the `current` array length, and array of the `next` nested arrays. If the `next` array is not empty, use the result of calling the function again. If not, return the `val`.

```js
const generateMulti = ([current, ...next], val) =>
  Array.from({ length: current }, () => next.length ?
    generateMulti(next, val) : val
  )

const result = generateMulti([3, 2, 2], null)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```